# Regex to replace all special characters except slashes?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to work out some regex that will eliminate all of the special characters that SharePoint won't take when creating a folder.

These are the characters that are not allowed and I am assuming that the bottom regex below will handle all of these. But I want to replace an \ or / with a dash as well.

```
~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }
```

So this is what I have so far, but I'm hoping to combine this all into one function, if possible.

```
 private void RemoveAndReplaceSpecialCharacters(string input)
    {
        Regex.Replace(input, @"\\", @"-");
        Regex.Replace(input, @"/", @"-");
        Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._]", string.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: It is already in one function... what exactly are you trying solve/accomplish?

Comment: @mallamokb I take it the requested solution is to combine the three function *calls* into one function *call*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `Regex.Replace` for the first two replacements, so you could combine those into one, or, since they are replaced by the same character, continue using `Regex.Replace` but only one of those.

```
private string RemoveAndReplaceSpecialCharacters(string input) {
    return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, @"[\\/]", "-"),
                         @"[^0-9a-zA-Z._]", string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void RemoveAndReplaceSpecialCharacters(string input)
    {
        Regex.Replace(input, @"[\\\/]+", "-");
            Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._]+", string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
var foo = @"aa\b\hehe";
var baa = Regex.Replace(foo, @"[^\\/]+", "-");
```