# C# how to remove all special characters EXCEPT underscore

Tags: c#

I need to create a method to remove all special characters except `_`.

Obviously the code below is not good!

This does show what I need though.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there a regex that will work, but then allow for `_` to be used?

```
        public static string SanitizeImportName(string importName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(importName) == true)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(importName));
            }

            return importName.Replace("!", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("@", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("#", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("$", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("%", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("^", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("&", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("*", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("(", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(")", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("-", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("+", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("=", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("/", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("\\", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("{", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("}", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("[", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("]", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("|", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(":", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(";", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("\"", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("'", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("<", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(">", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(",", string.Empty)
                             .Replace(".", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("?", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("~", string.Empty)
                             .Replace("`", string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to replace all special characters except slashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173366/) and [Replace all special character except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887607/) and [How to avoid all special characters except spaces in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542700/)

Comment: `Regex.Replace(importName, @"[!@#$...]+", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your special characters in a Regex pattern, then remove all special characters from your text by using the Replace method.

```
var regex = new Regex("[!@#$%\^&*\(\)-+=\/\\\{\}\[\]\|:;\"'<>,.\?\~`;]");

var result = regex.Replace("Some!D#Text_With%Special$Character", string.Empty);
```

The result would be "SomeText_WithSpecialCharacter".

Comment: I got it to work with the answer I posted. I couldn't get your example to work with everything including: `[` `]`

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 I added all of the characters that you wrote in the question to my answer, and it works.

Comment: yes, I was not adding in all property items with the RegEx. So your answer works as well! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The below example will remove all special characters except:   (space) and `_`.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var regex = "[^0-9A-Za-z_ ]";
        var importName = "54 w/% some_ text 999";
        Console.WriteLine("Before result: "  + importName);
        var result = Regex.Replace(importName, regex, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("After result: "  + result);
    }
        /*
        //var allNeedToBeRemoved = @"!@#$%^&*()-+={}|\\:;\"'<>,.?/";
        var regex = "[^0-9A-Za-z_ ]";
        //var regex = new Regex("[!@#$%^&*()+{|:;'<>,.?/~`\\/=-}]");
        //var regex = new Regex("[!@#$%^&*()+{|:;'<>,.?/~`\\/=-}]");
        //var regex = new Regex("[!@#$%^&*()+-]");      
        */  
}
```